# Quick way to clear only option available list on a multiselect with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

What is the shortest and quickest way to remove only option available list on a UI multiselect?

[image]

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: $("#multipleselectboxId").append(toAppend).multiselect("destroy").multiselect();

Comment: Its only add new option, not clean all list.

Comment: I suggest [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30747212/edit) to add the code you've tried and what went wrong. If possible, try to reproduce the problem you're having so that we can experience it. What is "toAppend"?